# Table Header does not hide

Tags: iphone, uitableview, header, uisearchbar

I am Using the Table view header view Search bar.The Problem is I scroll the Table View Search bar also scroll. I want always visible in Search bar.

Comment: where have u added the search bar ?

Comment: wt u wnat ?? and wt is ur problem >
?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if u add the search bar as the header view of the table then whenever you scroll the Table View Search bar also scroll. Its default behavior,but yes if you want to display always searchbar in the top of table view you can apply as Dilip said
check this link:
http://ved-dimensions.blogspot.in/2009/02/iphone-development-adding-search-bar-in.html

Answer (score 1):

Simply don't add your search bar in table header view. Add searchbar in your view and then table view below search bar.